# R if statement with try

Tags: r

I want to run an if statement where there's a chance that the first part will throw an error, e.g., rather than evaluating to false, it won't exist. If there is an error, I just want to continue down the code (this is part of a for loop). If it doesn't throw an error, I want to execute a little piece of code inside the if statement. I think there is just a brackets problem combining an if statement with try, but I can't figure it out.

```
try({
  test_selenium <- remDr$getStatus()[[2]] ##If this isn't running, it will throw an error
 if(test_selenium=="Server is running"){
    remDr$close() ##if it is running, test_selenium will say "server is running" and I want to run this code to close it
    rD$server$stop() 
      }
  )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am usually doing something like this, but I am not sure whether it works in your context.

```
if ( class(try(remDr$getStatus()[[2]], silent = TRUE)) == "try-error") {

        test_selenium <- remDr$getStatus()[[2]] ##If this isn't running, it will throw an error

        if(test_selenium=="Server is running"){
            remDr$close() ##if it is running, test_selenium will say "server is running" and I want to run this code to close it
            rD$server$stop() 
        } # close second if 
} # close first if
```

If the only possible values of getStatus() are either an error (which is acutally not a value) or "Server is running" then you can shorten the code to.

```
if ( class(try(remDr$getStatus()[[2]], silent = TRUE)) == "try-error") {

        remDr$close()  
        rD$server$stop() 

} # close  if
```